# Calling a custom adapter from a fragment

Tags: c#, android, listview, android-fragments

I am making an android app in visual studio, and I have encountered this problem multiple times.

I have a main activity with a main view and inside those I have multiple fragments, each with different tabs inside, each tab containing an expandable listview.

In order to fill that listview with items, I need a custom adapter. The custom adapter requires that I pass an activity when calling it, but I am doing this inside a fragment. Same thing when trying to call a toast from an adapter and it requires a context.

Any ideas?

Comment: Add a static activity field/property to your fragment and pass that to your Adapters.

Comment: pass getActivity() from fragment to custom adapter constructor